# How do I use search term exclusion on organic bot traffic in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have received bot traffic on my website recently that I am having trouble filtering out. In Google Analytics, it says that the traffic is from the Organic Search channel. When I click into Organic Search, it says that the keyword they used to get to my website is the URL for the traffic bot website (e.g. [www.botexample.com](http://www.botexample.com)). When I drop this URL into the search term exclusion tool in Property>Tracking Info, it doesn't actually filter anything out. That bot traffic will still appear in my Google Analytics home page.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`search term` is a different dimension from `kewyword`. The first is terms used in the internal search, the second is the keyword entered in Google Search. The second can't be used in a filter. So you have to find another identifier to use to exclude bot hits.